# Restrict window movement to parent window area

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2, ribbon

I'm working on a delphi program using the TRibbon and launching separate exe files.
Once I have executed the external application (with CreateProcessA() ) I set its parent as the form with the ribbon:

```
wHandle := FindWindow('MainRibbonForm');
Winapi.Windows.SetParent(wHandle,self.Handle);
```

All considered, this works alright, but the problem is that the application forms can be moved over the TRibbon in the main form. I was thinking about restricting the form's movement within the main application but how can I take into account the ribbon?

Comment: I'm not shure having understood your wishes. Something like placing the external Window maximized on a Panel and setting borderstyle to bsNone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a TPanel as a container on your Form and use this TPanel as Parent. Now the Child can only move inside the TPanel.

```
wHandle := FindWindow( 'MainRibbonForm' );
SetParent( wHandle, MyContainerPanel.Handle );
```